# Magento 1.9 Order Rest API Order Data

Tags: magento-1.9, api, sales-order, rest-api

Using magento rest API i can see the data of product, category etc using

https://magentohost/api/rest/products, Here is can see list of products but when i access

https://magentohost/api/rest/orders it says forbidden, I have assined all access to admin and guest but still it does not show it.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Orders/sales_orders.html

Here is my PHP code which works for product data but when i change products to orders it shows blank array

```
<?php



$callbackUrl = "http://localhost/magento_navo/rest.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://localhost/magento_navo/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://localhost/magento_navo/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://localhost/magento_navo/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://localhost/magento_navo/api/rest';

$consumerKey    = '5d93150171fa64e87ae316646f07b0ae';
$consumerSecret = '06b312b7b8ea4e7c6319f00bf49f1e35';


session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
       //$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/orders";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => '*/*'));
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {

    print_r($e);
```

**Output:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [41] => Array
        (
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
    )

[51] => Array
    (
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ACL Attribute Rules from System -> Web Services -> Rest Attributes

Answer (score 0):

Use Soap 1.1 instead of 1.2 if it fails to give you correct output like:

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'user_agent' => 'CustomSoapClient'
  )
);

$params = [
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 
    'trace' => 1, 
    'exceptions' => 1, 
    "connection_timeout" => 180, 
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
];

$host = "magentostore.com"; 
$client = new SoapClient("https://".$host."/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1",$params);
```